# Different arguments in Seq() in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax

In the code I am going through, a sequence having LocalDate type variables as elements has been passed to a function which in turn is been interpreted in the following way:

```
Seq(acquisitionDate: LocalDate, head: LocalDate, tail @ _*)
```

As far as I can understand, acquisitionDate is the last element, head is the first element and tail is all the elements in between.. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context it might be a pattern matching, which affect what is going on there (in a minor way, of course). acquisitionDate is the first **argument**, head is the second, tail is the rest (it will be expanded by the compiler into third, fourth and so on arguments). In addition there is type ascription, which *may* upcast variable to some specific type, but usually serves as a documentation. Without type ascription it might look like:

```
Seq(acquisitionDate, head, tail @ _*)
```

Comment: Okay. I think I got it.In my case, 'acquisitionDate' would be the first element of the sequence, 'head' would be the second argument of the seequence and 'tail' would be the rest of the sequence. Right?